# Has anyone successfully setup Mandrill with CiviMail for bulk?

Tags: civimail, integration, smtp, mandrill

In the past (v. 4.5.x) I tested CiviMail for bulk mailings and had lots of trouble process bounces via the return channel.  I know there is a wonderful plugin for transactional emails, but for bulk mailing, Mandrill is very reasonable and provides some great complimentary reports.  I expect it *should* work with Mandrill's SMTP functionality directly.

**So before I dive in, I'm simply asking if anyone has gotten this to work and if so, could you please share your config.**

Comment: FYI - The Mandrill extension now supports bulk mail (2.0).  I have been using it and it works .... however I have run into some problems which are noted in the issue queue: https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.mte/issues .  It can get pretty complicated to debug.  I also discovered that the next minor release should support Mandrill SMTP bounces which is all I really need and will try that next: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16584?jql=text%20~%20%22mandrill%22 to simplify things.

Comment: **NOTE: Using Mandrill for CiviMail bulk mailings is against the Mandrill T&C and if they detect you doing so they will lock/cancel your account with very little notice**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been doing some testing with the last release of the [Mandrill Emails Extension](https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.mte) and it's looking pretty quick and simple with the new version to do both transactional and bulk mailing (CiviMail) through Mandrill. Basically you install it, plug in your Login/API credentials (**Administer > System Settings > Mandrill Smtp Settings**), and indicate one or both of the types of email you'd like to use Mandrill for:
[image: Mandrill CiviCRM SMTP].

To get the report backs on bounces and the like, you use the "Mandrill Post to URL" on that screen to set up a Webhook in your Mandrill account and get notifications for all events except a message being sent:

[image: Mandrill webhook]

In the little testing I've been able to do, it seems pretty much plug-and-play in terms of the bounce reporting getting back into CiviCRM.

The [updated README is quite thorough](https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.mte/blob/master/README.md), too.

Answer (score 1):

There were a lot of people at CiviCon Denver at the dev ops session using Mandrill for bulk email.  I'm not one of them so don't have a config to share, but can confirm that some very experienced providers use it. It was more popular than CiviSMTP or Amazon SES. The only one I recall specifically is CiviDesk, who praised the ability to use sub accounts to track their clients' usage separately. Shoot them an email perhaps?

Comment: Cool. Now I'm encouraged to try again and see what the issue was but If someone could share a working configuration that would be swell.

Comment: Jon can you edit your answer to clarify if people were using this for bulk, mass emailing through CiviCRM or just transactional? As far as I can tell from the extension https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.mte/issues/80 no work was yet done on bounce handling.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this new extension? https://civicrm.org/extensions/mandrill-email

I tested it. Mandrill processes the bounced emails but Civicrm doesn't pick it up. I might have a settings wrong or missing. Let us know if you find something.

Comment: Works now! I forgot to create the webhook in mandrill

Comment: Works now! I forgot to create the webhook in mandrill